# How to insert and retrieve at the same time in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have a table named `Domain_Test` and column are:-

1. ID
2. Domain
3. Processed

Here `ID` is `auto increment` and `Domain` contains links and `processed` contains 0. Basically i need a query through which I can retrieve the `domain` and at the same time need to update `processed` column to 1. And I'm using java to do all this.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I dnt get you. please describe little..

Comment: Why do you need to do this in one statement?

Comment: @Lennart, If it is possible in one statement or not then tell me the other ways to do it.

Comment: @RajeevArora do it in 2 queris

Comment: It is not possible. You cannot do it in single statement. Though you can set series of statements that might seem to do at same time

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, it sounds straight-forward. Use a transaction, first retrive the domain, then update the status

Comment: A simple (maybe dumb) example: can you use a single pencil (with an eraser at one end) to both write and erase a previous word? You need to perform two separate instructions, one to read data (`select`) and another to modify data (`update`, `insert` or `delete`). You can do it either sequentially, you can use transactions to ensure that all is done correctly, or (if you can "isolate" each task) use multiple threads to read and write simultaneously. But all depends on what you need to do, and how you need to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible. I am assuming the reason you want to do it in a single statement is to make sure the record is not updated between your two statements.

What you need to do is to use a transaction. Inside the transaction, first do the update, then the select. Then you commit the transaction. The atomicity of the transaction guarantees that the value of the doman you read is the same as when you set the processed flag.

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE Domain_Test SET processed=1 WHERE id=YourId
SELECT Doman FROM Domain_Test WHERE id=YourId
COMMIT;
```

For more info about transactions in mysql, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html .

Answer (score 2):

you cannot `retrieve` and `update` in a single statement, there are 2 steps

```
select domain from thatTable where id = 100 -- retrieve the value in domain
```

to update:

```
update thatTable     set processed = NOW()     where id = 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this,

```
public static int retrieveAndUpdate(Connection connection) throws SQLException{
    try {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);

        String querySelect = "SELECT processed FROM Domain_Test WHERE id=YourId";
        String queryUpdate = "UPDATE Domain_Test SET processed=? WHERE id=YourId";

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryUpdate);

        ResultSet resultSet = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(querySelect);

        if (!resultSet.next()) {
            return 0;
        } else { // This block is running, if the query is retrieved some data
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1);
                preparedStatement.addBatch();
            }
            int[] batchUpdate = preparedStatement.executeBatch();
            for (int result : batchUpdate) {
                if (result == 0) {
                    connection.rollback();// When update process gets an error, stop the current process.
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        connection.commit(); //If Retrieving and Updating is success, data will be commited to the DB
        return 1;

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        connection.rollback(); // // When update process gets SQLException, current process will be stopped.
        throw ex;

    }
}
```

This will be commit your data to DB, if all the processes are succeed.